# Use Gradle to complete multilevel directory projects

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle and I want to ask if Gradle can implement this kind of project structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can, and it is called multi-project builds. For information on it, take a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) in the Gradle user guide.

If you are completely new to Gradle, you may want to follow a guide such as [this one](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) for creating the basic structure.